# R Server can't find Imported Python Modules after reboot

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, server, python-module

We had to restart our R Server (*EC2 box*), and following its restart, my Jupyter notebooks are throwing errors that regularly-used, imported modules cannot be found:

(in Jupyter Notebook cell)

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
```

> ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

But when I used the command line to verify that the module is imported (based off of the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588390/how-do-i-check-whether-a-module-is-installed-in-python-and-install-it-if-needed)), I saw that it was still present in the system. Is there something I'm missing, here?

```
    (base)$ python -c "import MySQLdb"
    (base)$ echo $?
    0
```

For context, the Jupyter file used was using the MySQLdb module prior to the restart of the server. Also, not sure if it's important to know, but I had to [reconnect my hard drive from the command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mount-drive-from-command-line-ubuntu-linux/) line post-reboot as well:

```
sudo  mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/ebs
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some back-tracking, we were able to resolve the issue!

**Jupyter was initiated prior to mounting the server to the hard drive. Our Python modules are within the Anaconda environment in the server, and without the hard drive's connection to the server, the imported Jupyter pointed to the computer's python environment.**

Posting steps on how we resolved the issue in case it comes up for others:

1. We rebooted the server again. This was to give the reconnection channels a re-start.
2. After a reboot:

```
➜  ~ ssh # onto the EC2 box 

(base):~$ sudo  mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/ebs # reattach external drive 

(base):~$ screen -S somenameforscreensession # start a screen session (persistent session)

(base):~$ jupyter notebook --port=#### # start jupyter within that persistent session
```